# Is decltype's result for template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

Is the result of `decltype` the same as the template identifier? (And what is the correct term when referring to T and its value?). That is are there cases where the assert fails?

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T x)
{
  static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(x), T>::value, "decltype check failed");
}
```

Comment: "And what is the correct term?" `T` is a *template parameter* and its value is a *template argument*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type of the variable `x` is T, therefore that static_assert is always going to pass.

Comment: Could that change for some modifications, e.g. `decltype((x))`?

Comment: I am sorry, I could and should have checked that myself. The reason I am asking is because I think it is hard to understand the finer details of decltype and template parameter deduction.